# How to get terrain height from PlaneBufferGeometry in Three.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to find the height of a procedural terrain at x,z (0,0) from the procedural terrain example on the three js website:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_terrain_dynamic.html

I have tried to use of a raycaster placed 'above' the terrain, guided downwards with a normalized vector. No matter what I do, the projected ray seems to pass 'through' the generated terrain at (0,-125,0). The y component stays fixed at -125, but you would expect it to change with the terrain undulations?

```
scene.updateMatrixWorld(true);

var raycaster_dir_vector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 400, 0);
var down = new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0);
raycaster.set(raycaster_dir_vector , down.normalize());
var collisionresults = raycaster.intersectObjects([terrain], true);
```

Comment: Noise is generated in the vertex shader. Raycaster works with vertices of a geometry on javascript side and knows nothing about how they were modified in the shader.

Comment: Is there anyway I can output the noise displacement from the shader?